# Prevent a key from turning keyboard backlight back on

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, vlc, karabiner, backlight

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro running 10.15.3, and I'd like to be able to turn the keyboard backlight off (without simply turning it all the way down) when watching a full-screen video, but allow it to return if any key *other than the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>* is pressed. The ultimate goal is to make the keyboard backlight less intrusive when watching a video, and allow pausing and un-pausing of a video without activating the keyboard backlight. However, *if a key other than the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pressed*, this 'mode' would be cancelled, and everything returned to normal, until the user again chooses to (provisionally) deactivate the keyboard backlight. I can't find any ways to do this in the OS or with any third-party software, including Karabiner (which I don't use, but can't find references to backlight) or through any preference or extension to VLC.

The "Turn keyboard backlight off after [...] seconds of activity" setting in `Keyboard` within `System Preferences` would need to remain unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Why not use an Apple Remote for pausing and starting? That should bypass having to hit the keyboard at all.

Comment: @user136952 To which remote are you referring? MacBook Pros after 2016 no longer have IR sensors, so you cannot use any of the Apple Remotes (either the original white or the new aluminum). I'd also prefer not to have to always use an additional device for this purpose.